# Stuck on old build in production Angular15

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to move my MEAN web app from heroku to another hosting site, however I am stuck on Angular not "generating" a new build even though I change angular files, for example a console.log I added yesterday is still printing out even though I have deleted it.

Locally everything works ok.

What I have tried so far:

- ng cache clean
- npm cache clean
- deleting node_modules
- Hard refresh / incognito mode
- deploying multiple times / starting from zero
- removing service worker
- restarting vscode/laptop
- running ng build --configuration=production --aot --outputHashing=all

Comment: can you describe your pipeline ?

Answer (score 1):

Running the following seems to fix the problem:

```bash
ng build --output-path build --configuration=production
```

Comment: --aot is already included inside production configuration.